# C++ iterator as class member used in class method

Tags: c++, iterator

i have the following code.

The for-loop at the end should go through the object of CCarList class, print out the the a_rz and vin of Car structure and stop when the AtEnd() method returns true.

But it doesnt stop and moreover when i try to reach the values of a_rz and vin it gives segmentation fault.

Could someone, please, explain how to use properly iterator in my CCarList class?

Thanks

```
    typedef struct Car {

        string a_rz;
        unsigned int vin;
    }Car;

    class CCarList
     {
       public:
        string         RZ           ( void ) const;
        unsigned int   VIN          ( void ) const;
        bool           AtEnd        ( void ) const;
        void           Next         ( void );

        vector<Car*> vCar;
        vector<Car*>::const_iterator it = vCar.begin();
       public:
                       CCarList     ( void ){}
                       ~CCarList    ( void ){}
     };

     string CCarList::RZ ( void ) const {
        return "ahoj"; //(**it).a_rz;
     }
    unsigned int CCarList::VIN ( void ) const{
        return 5; //(**it).vin;
    }
    bool CCarList::AtEnd ( void ) const {

        if(it == vCar.end()) return true;
        return false;
    }
    void  CCarList::Next ( void ){
        it++;
    }

    int main() {


    Car  *a, *b, *c;
    a = new Car;
    b = new Car;
    c = new Car;

    (*a).a_rz = "abc";
    (*a).vin = 45;
    (*b).a_rz = "dfg";
    (*b).vin = 65;
    (*c).a_rz = "jkl";
    (*c).vin = 23;

    CCarList list_of_cars;
    list_of_cars.vCar.push_back(a);
    list_of_cars.vCar.push_back(b);
    list_of_cars.vCar.push_back(c);

    for ( ; ! list_of_cars . AtEnd (); list_of_cars . Next () )
         cout << list_of_cars . RZ () << ", " << list_of_cars . VIN () << endl;


    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is broken.  That iterator should be set to the beginning only when you need to start the iteration.  Calling `push_back` may invalidate `it` right from the start.  Also, if I want to go through the list two or more times, where is the function to set the iterator to the beginning?  Needless to say, having a member that is an iterator is a strange (might even say flawed) design.

Comment: This code is part of my different program. What is here in the main function (except the loop) is there in function which is supposed to create temporary object to go through the vector just once and in that function i assign this vector content from different vector from database. Methods RZ(), VIN(), AtEnd() and Next() have to be there - its the task. I couldnt figure out any other way to do it that with iterator as class member. What would be your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that iterator `it` is not being updated/invalidated after each `push_back`. After last insertion it still points to "nothing" as it was from beginning.

Soultion is simple -- update your iterator. Add a method for adding new elements:

```
void CCarList::Add(Car* car) 
{
    vCar.push_back(car);
    it = vCar.begin();
}
```

and then just:

```
list_of_cars.Add(a);
list_of_cars.Add(b);
list_of_cars.Add(c);
```

Also regarding above problem, you're trying to wrap `vector` and provide same functionality that `vector`already provides. Consider moving functionality related to `Car` structure inside that structure. And leaving in `CCarList` only methods that are related to `CCarList`. Just a short piece of code to show you what I mean:

```
typedef struct Car {
    string a_rz;
    unsigned int vin;
} Car;

class CCarList {
public:
    vector<Car*> vCar;
    CCarList(void){}
    ~CCarList(void){}
};

int main() {

    Car  *a, *b, *c;
    a = new Car;
    b = new Car;
    c = new Car;

    a->a_rz = "abc";
    a->vin = 45;
    b->a_rz = "dfg";
    a->vin = 65;
    c->a_rz = "jkl";
    c->vin = 23;

    CCarList list_of_cars;

    list_of_cars.vCar.push_back(a);
    list_of_cars.vCar.push_back(b);
    list_of_cars.vCar.push_back(c);

    for(auto car : list_of_cars.vCar)
        cout << car->a_rz << ", " << car->vin << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense for me now :)  ... and i know there probably d be easier way to do that but the for-loop was given to us at school and we had to implement the class according that :)